# Splitting up the date using sscanf

Tags: php

I have a date like this

```
2015-10-09T19:30:00

list($y, $M, $d, $h, $m, $s) = sscanf($instance->Start, "$d-$d-$dT$d:$d:$d");
```

^ I am trying to apply this `sscanf` to split the components up but I am getting bugs at the T section

ultimately want something like this

```
$z = "Europe/London";
$timestamp = $d."-".$M."-".$y."T".$h.":".$m.":".$s." ".$z;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` Interface -

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-10-09T19:30:00');
echo $date->format('d-m-Y').' T '.$date->format('H:i:s').' Europe/London';
```

**Output**

```
09-10-2015 T 19:30:00 Europe/London
```

correct answer

```
echo $date->format('d-m-Y').' UTC '.$date->format('H:i:s').' Europe/London';
```

Comment: its close - but I am getting 2:30am when converting it to a unix timestamp             date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
            $date = new DateTime($instance->Start);
            $tmp["FullData"] = strtotime($date->format('d-m-Y').' T '.$date->format('H:i:s').' Europe/London');

Comment: You have to change the timezone as `T` -> `UTC`

Comment: but i need the timezone to be GMT - London time... so really its got to come out 19:30

Comment: are you saying ... echo $date->format('d-m-Y').' UTC '.$date->format('H:i:s').' Europe/London';

Comment: Then set it to that timezone.

Comment: I think you fixed it man. Thank you - man that was a mind scramble

Comment: So what is T  -- I thought that was the standard indicator for the DateTime to know that that is TIME

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$date = "2015-10-09T19:30:00";
$z = "Europe/London";

sscanf($date, "%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d", $year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$timestamp = $day."-".$month."-".$year."T".$hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds." ".$z;
echo $timestamp;

?>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.